# Try to add new file name in URLSessionDownloadTask is finished

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsession

I am downloading some files and try to save the file after download is done. Now I try to suggest a new name when file is already exist. here is my code :

```
  public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

        if let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
        {
            let newLocation = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectoryPath).appendingPathComponent(nameOfDownload!)
            do {
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: newLocation!)
                print("\(String(describing: newLocation))")
            }
            catch {
                print("error moving file")
            }
        }
  }
```

If file is already exists I will get error of `error moving file` how can I suggest new name ? for example if `file.zip` is on document directory new file name should be `file(2).zip` ?

Comment: Or you have an array with your files name and control over that or you do a try/error... file.zip exists, try again file(1).zip, if exists, try again file(2).zip. But it is quite amateur. I would concatenate a random number to file name everytime

Comment: You can append timestamp in your file name, so every time you download file, it will be unique always.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar This is good idea , but I will wait for more suitable answer

Comment: iterate all the files with the name if it exists, then increment the counter.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar I know but how can detect current number ?! for example if file exists with `file2.zip` the next file mus be `..3.zip`